# Ubuntu 16.04 deb packages for ROS2 Bouncy Bolson?

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now there are no deb packages for Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) ([ros2 wiki ROS2 Bouncy Bolson Release Notes](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Release-Bouncy-Bolson#supported-platforms)). Will there be some in the future?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296621/ubuntu-16.04-deb-packages-for-ros2-bouncy-bolson?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-07-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the referenced release page says there are only Debian packages for Ubuntu Bionic. No, there won't be any Debian packages for Ubuntu Xenial.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-07-07**:
Thanks Dirk.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-07-07**:
For future reference: platforms targeted by each ROS 2 distribution (including which ones will have debs) is available on [REP2000](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/blob/master/rep-2000.rst#bouncy-bolson-june-2018---june-2019)